# Django unable to upload image file

Tags: python, django, model

I was trying out ImageField in the models, But Image upload do not work when I try to upload from the forms. But it works when I upload it from the admin page.

Any way to debug is also helpful

My model-

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    """docstring for Inventory"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Something')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Describe Something')
    price = models.IntegerField( default=0)
```

My Form-

```
class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ['name','description','price','image']

        widgets = {
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Name", "onfocus":"this.value = '';","onblur":"if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue","required":""}),
            'description' : forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email", "onfocus":"this.value = '';","onblur":"if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue","required":""}),
            'price' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Price","onfocus":"this.value = '';","onblur":"if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue","required":""}),
            
        }
```

Settings -

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

template -

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

url -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('inventory.urls')),
    path('<int:id>',include('inventory.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My Views-

```
def index(request):
    form = InventoryForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = InventoryForm()
    else:
        form = InventoryForm()

    inventory = Inventory.objects.all()
    context = {'form' : form, 'all_inventory' : inventory}
    return render(request, 'inventory/index.html',context)
```

Regards,
Deepak Dash

Comment: The problem might be in your **views.py**. Files are received using `request.FILES`. Make sure you aren't using `request.POST` for files

Comment: I added the views.py file also

Comment: I've added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **views.py**. Change:

`form = InventoryForm(request.POST or None)`

to

`form = InventoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)`

Because, Files in django post request are in **request.FILES** dictionary. You have to send that to forms as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding upload_to in models in image field and add default image also this will come in handy later on or not your choice:

```
models.py

class Inventory(models.Model):
    """docstring for Inventory"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Something')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/your_file_name/',default='default.png')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Describe Something')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: I could try that, But its not the good practice. I want to use the media_url and media_settings